# Impor a joomla websie database

Tags: sql, mysql, web, joomla, phpmyadmin

I've downloaded the website files using filezilla, now i need to import the website database,

i've have access to the website via administrator panel and via ftp.
i've also phpMyadmin configured with my local host

how to import the database of this website ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin has an Export / Import function that can serve a bzip compressed archive. See the "Export" tab.

If you don't have SSH access to the remote machine to do a `mysqldump`, that is your best option.

Comment: But this version that i have didn't allow me to change server from localhost.

Comment: @Excelecior you need phpMyAdmin installed on your remote server

Comment: i think it's installed because it's a joomla website, how can i have access to it ?

Comment: @Excelecior I don't know. But I don't think phpMyAdmin is a part of Joomla

Comment: sure it's not, but it's used frequently with joomla. thanks for your help

Comment: @Excelecior it's impossible to tell you how to access your phpMyAdmin when you don't know where it is located. Log in using FTP, and search for a folder of the name, it's likely to be there

Comment: @Excelecior. You need to login to the cPanel console to get access to the phpMyAdmin section. You will never find phpMyAdmin within Joomla as they are not part of the same package. Find out how you login to your hosting server and find phpMyAdmin within it.